# How to declare two conditions in an if else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hey I was wanting to display an indicator for being opened (very much like Yelp's indicator "Open Now") on a retail's store web site. I have figured out how to do it for set hours everyday (example Below).

But the shop has different closing times on Friday & Saturday, & is closed on Sundays. I am wanting to hopefully find a way to if/else those variables into this equation as well.

Or to account for those changes in order to make the indicator on the web site accurate.

```
 // JavaScript Document
var today = new Date(); 
var dayNow = today.getDay();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var shopStatus


if (dayNow = 0) {
    shopStatus = 'See you on Monday';
}

// Regular Hours for Monday - Thursday  
// night time message 
else if  (hourNow > 21) {
        dayNow < 4
        shopStatus = 'Open at 7am';
}   
// closed hours message
else if (hourNow >18 ) {
        dayNow < 5
        shopStatus = '<p class="red">Closed Now</p>';
}   
// 6:30pm closing soon message
else if (hourNow > 17.5) {
        dayNow < 4
        shopStatus = 'Closing soon';
}   
//  Mon - Thurs. open hours message
else if (hourNow > 7 ) {
        dayNow < 4
        shopStatus = 'Open Now';
}   
// 6:30am opening soon
else if (hourNow > 6.5) {
        dayNow < 4
        shopStatus = 'Opening Soon';
}
document.write('<p>' + shopStatus + '</p>');
```

Comment: Statements like `dayNow < 4` do nothing at all.

Comment: Also I think you're looking for [the `&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: dayNow = 0 just sets dayNow to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create quite complicated conditions using `&&`, `||` for AND, OR:

```
if (dayNow == 0) {
  shopStatus = 'See you on Monday'; // Sunday - closed
}
else if ( dayNow == 1 )  && 
   ( hourNow > openingHour ) && 
   ( hourNow < closeToClose ) { // Monday opening hours
  shopStatus = 'message' ;
// next tests...
```

Personally, I would prefer another approach. Create array with simple index of shop states. Oooh - how it goes...

```
var shopStatus = ["Open", "Closed", "Closing soon!"];
```

check the state with simple (not so simple) test:

```
if (
    ( dayNow < 6 ) && ( dayNow > 1) // it's not Sun/Mon/Sat
    && ( hourNow < 17.5 ) && ( hourNow > 7 )
   ) // and it's open, OR
   || (
    ( dayNow == 1 ) || ( dayNow == 6 )
   ) { // it's Monday or Saturday
  document.write('<p>' + shopStatus[0] + '</p>');
    // message is "Open"
}
else if  // I think you are there
```

Write down all conditions for each status with particular array index. This solution is quite clean and very easy to translate later, if needed. I suggest to comment all conditions for easier debugging.

For more info, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple conditions in if you should use

**&&**  for AND

Or

**||** for OR

Like

If (condition1 == 5 && condition2 > 12){
}

Remember that when you compare condition, you should always use == instead of =

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out, at least it works now, I tried switching the clock on my computer to test it on the odd days (friday & saturday). Let me know what you think; but this works on the site I am using it on just fine.

```
var today = new Date(); 
var dayNow = today.getDay();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var shopStatus

/*dayNow determins if it is Friday, Saturday or Sunday */

if (dayNow == 0 || dayNow == 6 && hourNow > 16) {
  shopStatus = '<p class="orange">See you on Monday'; // Sunday - closed
}
// night message
else if  (hourNow > 21 && dayNow < 5 && dayNow > 0) {
        shopStatus = 'Open at 7am';
}
// Late Friday night message
else if ( dayNow == 5 && hourNow > 21) {
        shopStatus = '<p class="red">Open at 9am</p>';
}
// insert right after closed message
else if ( dayNow == 5 && hourNow > 14) {
        shopStatus = '<p class="red">Closed Now</p>';
}
/*Regular Hours for Monday - Thursday   
closed hours */

else if (hourNow >18 ) {
        shopStatus = '<p class="red">Closed Now</p>';
}   
// 6:30pm closing soon
else if (hourNow > 17.5) {
        shopStatus = 'Closing soon';
}   
//  Mon - Thurs. open hours
else if (hourNow > 7 ) {
        shopStatus = 'Open Now';
}   
// 6:30am opening soon
else if (hourNow > 6.5) {
        shopStatus = 'Opening Soon';
}

document.write('<p>' + shopStatus + ' *</p>');
```